# How do browsers generate bold fonts when only regular is specified?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, webfonts

I am using the font [Baloo 2](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Baloo+2) on some website. I loaded only the "regular" (i.e. 400) weight variant of the font, but on both Chrome and Firefox, it looks slightly different when `font-weight: bold` (or 700) is used.

Arguably, the Chrome version of the "bold" font looks better, but it's interesting that "Chrome bold" is somewhere between 500 and 600 while "Firefox bold" is only slightly bolder than 400.

I'm curious about where these "bold" variants come from, and how I could get a consistent look across browsers.

---

Please check the following example:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Baloo 2';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://gstatic.loli.net/s/baloo2/v1/wXKrE3kTposypRyd51jcAA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

b {
  /* Not important, just to be absolutely sure */
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

.example {
  font-family: 'Baloo 2';
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
  <p><b>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</b></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. The b element tells it it's bold. In the debugging tools chrome says a b element is 700 weight.

Comment: @LarryBud There's no bold font specified via `@font-face` but the text looks bold. It's a mysterious that the "bold variant of the font" comes out of nowhere.

Comment: It's not out of nowhere, you have the second sentence wrapped in a <b> element. The browser doesn't need a specific bold font to bold something.

Comment: @LarryBud For the text to actually look bold, a "bold variant" of the *font* is required, in addition to specifying `font-weight`. It's not a question about the `font-weight` item, but the displayed font face (glyph set). Can you back up your claim that *browser doesn't need a specific bold font*?

Comment: Tons of articles on the subject of a "faux bold": https://www.google.com/search?q=browser+renders+a+faux+bold&oq=browser+renders+a+faux+bold&aqs=chrome..69i57.4092j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: It's also why the faux bold renders differently in each browser. BTW, it also can do this with italics.

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/watch-your-font-weight/) but basically, you need 2 things. Set the h tags to all use the specific font-weight, hack the font weight to -100 of that.

You can use a class to make it bold if you want

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Baloo 2';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://gstatic.loli.net/s/baloo2/v1/wXKrE3kTposypRyd51jcAA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

b { // insure adding bold won't jack you up!
  font-family: 'Baloo 2';
  font-weight: 200 !important;
}

.bold {
  font-family: 'Baloo 2';
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
   font-family: 'Baloo 2';
   font-weight: 400; /* Be specific */
}

.example {
  font-family: 'Baloo 2';
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  <- P tag</p>
  <p><b>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<- Bold</b></p>
  <h4>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. <- H4</h4>
  <h4><b>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. <- H4 Bold</b></h4>
</div>
 <p class="bold">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  <- Class bold</p>
```